MLKit iOS Undefined symbols for architecture arm64
Я установил mlkit для ios через cocoapods, но даже не могу собрать.
Я не эксперт в ios, постарался поискать связанные проблемы, но решения не нашел.
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:

  "_CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer", referenced from:

      -[MLKVisionImage initWithBuffer:] in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

      -[MLKVisionImage initWithMLImage:] in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

  "_CMSampleBufferIsValid", referenced from:

      -[MLKVisionImage initWithBuffer:] in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKITx_FBMLImageInfo", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in MLKitVision(MLKVisionImage.o)

  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MLKTextRecognizer", referenced from:

      objc-class-ref in shared.framework.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

